# Customizing date on pandas bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df.head()

ORD905  ORD906  ORD907  ORD908
Year                
2000-01-01  0   0   0   2
2001-01-01  0   3   2   5
2002-01-01  0   6   6   2
2003-01-01  0   2   2   5
2004-01-01  0   1   0   0
```

I now want to plot this as a stacked bar plot and do so like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))


df['ORD905','ORD906', 'ORD907', 'ORD908']].plot(ax=ax, color=['red','blue','green','orange'],kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

However, this displays the x-ticks as 'yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss' and I want to just display the year. I have tried several different solutions and none seem to work. For example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

df[['ORD905','ORD906', 'ORD907', 'ORD908']].plot(ax=ax, color=['red','blue','green','orange'],kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

This does nothing. If I had the dateformatter line after, it gives me this error:

```
ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date; this usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the value printed on the axis (1970-01-01 00:00:00) is just the output of `str(ticklabel)`. Assuming the type of the index is `datetime` and not string, you can format your index by doing as follow:

```py
import datetime as dt
df.index.map(lambda date: dt.datetime.strftime(date, "%Y"))

# Or simply
df.index.map("{:%Y}".format)
```

[EDIT]: If that fails, you can always format the labels yourself:

```
import datetime as dt

def format_date(date_str):
    if date_str == "":
        return ""
    return "{:%Y}".format(dt.datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

ax.set_xticklabels([format_date(tl.get_text()) for tl in ax.get_xticklabels()])
```

Comment: This does not change the x-ticks when plotting. They are still in the format I listed in my original post.